# How to find oversold stocks?

Tags: stock-analysis

How do I find whether the stock is oversold or not? What technical factor of the stock that I need to look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oversold is when a security  asset trades much lower in price due to an overreaction by traders.  It tends to be due to bad news, often exacerbated by the market dropping as well. It's a subjective determination made by traders and investors.

For investors, oversold is when share price is no longer equal to its actual value.  For example, current P/E as well as forward P/E.

Technical traders will look for oversold and overbought levels in the price domain and/or extreme values in technical indicators.  For example, RSI or Stochastics.

Note that oversold conditions can last for a long time. Just because price is much lower today, there's no way to know that price won't drop even lower.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically asking, "how can I find stocks that will go up soon?". What sort of answer are you expecting?

Oversold is a term most often used in technical analysis to describe a stock that has been "sold off" at an unusually high intensity, indicating an irrational panic in the market and supposedly heralding an imminent "return to normal". People look at price trends, historical moving averages, trading volume and any number of indicators. There are 1000 and 1 ways to do it with varying degrees of success. Even just measuring which ways work well and don't is a major open question in the field. Coming up with a sure fire solution is certainly out of scope for an answer on this site.

Comment: Not really the question is "how can I find stocks that will go up soon?" You mentioned some indicators like price trends, historical moving averages, trading volume etc... The problem is that I can't go through thousands of stocks one by one to find them. I would rather prefer use some stock scanner to find them. But I want to know the technical factors or indicators that I can use in those search web sites.

Comment: @wonderful world - In order to select technical indicators to use in scanning, you need to understand what the indicator depicts as well as its limitations.  Then you have to define your criteria for a stock to be considered oversold.  The scanning is the easy part.  Figuring out what conditions are acceptable to you is not.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as oversold. Sometimes stocks go down in price. When that happens some people think it went down more than is justified - but certainly not the people who sold it!

You know what's REALLY oversold? "Technical" analysis - which is pretty much looking for shapes in the clouds. Good luck.